# Is there a way you can specify a custom ROLES table to use just like you can specify the USERS table in Websecurity.InitializeDatabase()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, roleprovider

So I know you can specify what custom table you would like to use for the Users table when utilizing the [InitializeDatabase method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569134%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) on the WebMatrix.WebData.Websecurity class, but I wanted to find out if there is no way to specify the Roles table to use?  There might not be any reason - except if you wanted more control over what data is stored with a role.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to specific roles table in `Websecurity.InitializeDatabase()`

but for example you can include Asp.net Simple Membership tables as part of your entity framework model and more control over it.

[This article](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model) might assist you in resolving your issue.